# data id iteration django

Tags: django, django-templates

I really do not know how to iterate through my loop to display individual items. I have tried to 
rearrange the loop but has worked. The data id id="portfolioModal" is what I want to also iterate for individual items.

```
{% for subjects in object %}
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="portfolioModal1Label" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">
              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </span>
          </button>
          <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">

                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <!-- Portfolio Modal - Title -->

                  <h2 class="portfolio-modal-title text-success text-uppercase mb-0">{{subjects.title}}</h2>
                  <!-- Icon Divider -->
                  <div class="divider-custom">
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Portfolio Modal - Image -->
                  <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle mb-5" src=" {{subjects.img.url}}" alt="">
                  <!-- Portfolio Modal - Text -->
                 <p>{{subjects.desc}}</p>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fas fa-times fa-fw"></i>
                    Close Window
                  </button>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try to explain it better. You want to iterate the div id? Which values do you want to be use?

Comment: @Tané yes, I am trying to iterate through the div id, so I can remove code repetition for individual id="portfolioModal" such as id="portfolioModal1",id="portfolioModal2" , etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate just numbers in the loop, you can use the `{{ forloop.counter }}`, like this:

```
{% for subjects in object %}
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal-{{ forloop.counter }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="portfolioModal1Label" aria-hidden="true">

...

{% endfor %}
```

In the for loop inside your template code, ever single object of your the context "object" variable is named "subjects", like you know. So, If you want iterate your div id using a object attribute (suppose object.id), just call it by `{{ subjects.id }}`:

```
{% for subjects in object %}
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal-{{ subjects.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="portfolioModal1Label" aria-hidden="true">

...

{% endfor %}
```

When this page is rendered,this will print a simple id=portfolioModal-1, id=portfolioModal-2, id=portfolioModal-3... where numbers are the objects ids

Comment: It worked, by adding id="portfolioModal-{{ subjects.id }}" and referencing the data target data-target="#portfolioModal-{{subjects.id }}". The individual items were displayed. Thanks again @Tané